# Drag and Drop in CodeName One

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to build an application in which I need to select widget from menu & drop it on Container (Not CUT & Paste, But select widget & Create its corresponding instance on other Container) in Drag & drop way.

I am not able find any help on this. Please help.

So far, I have done this,

```
Label label = new Label("Top Left");
label.setPreferredW(200);
label.setPreferredH(30);
label.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xff0000);
label.setDraggable(true);
stateMachine.findForm().addComponent(label);

// Setting parent can be recieve drop
stateMachine.findElementContainer().setDropTarget(true);

Container c = new MyContainer();
stateMachine.findElementContainer().addComponent(c);
```

---

```
public class MyContainer extends Container {

    public MyContainer() {
        this.setDropTarget(true);
    } 

    @Override
    public void drop(Component dragged, int x, int y) {
        System.err.println(dragged + " : " + x + " : " + y);
    }

}
```

But Method,

```
public void drop(Component dragged, int x, int y) {
```

is not being invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You set both the ElementContainer and its child as drop targets. You add c into the Elements container but since its a `FlowLayout` (the default) it won't size much and I'm assuming that ElementContainer doesn't have the right size of layout to give it the proper size.

Set the layout of ElementContainer to `BorderLayout` place c in the center and don't make the ElementContainer a drop target too. You should look at the how do I videos specifically the one dealing with layout managers. Setting the preferred size isn't the right direction.